# How to transpose in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table:
[image: Before]

And I want to make it like this in Oracle SQL:
[image: After]

How can I write code in SQL?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select subjid,
       max(case when status = 'most recent dose' then date end) as most_recent_dose
       max(case when status = 'second most recent dose' then date end) as second_most_recent_dose
       max(case when status = 'dosing' then date end) as dosing
  from your_table
group by subjid
```